# How to I fix 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: mysql, express, view, sequelize.js

Now, I have some server error problem.
I request to the server from react client and then server can not response.
I find an error position in my project.It comes from sequelize Database.

```
exports.createMemeber = (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
const { email, password } = req.body;
***author.findByPK(email)***
    .then(res => {
        res.send(email);
        res.end();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(400).send('No Validate')
    })}
```

The main error position is

```
author.findByPK...
```

In this part there will be error in console window.

Comment: The code example is incomplete but you should read the error in the console, it will likely help explain the issue.

Comment: What can I do, I am sure to complete the code.

Comment: What does the error show? You should edit your post to include the error message.

Comment: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "F:\Node\express_mvc\public"
    at Function.render (F:\Node\express_mvc\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (F:\Node\express_mvc\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at F:\Node\express_mvc\app.js:40:7
    at Layer.handle_error (F:\Node\express_mvc\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix  at next (F:\Node\express_mvc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

Comment: This is my error.I already used a lot of approached to correct this error.I do not use any render() function

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language and the Sequelize docs show the method as `findByPk` (note the lower-case k).

Ref: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findByPk

Try to change findByP**K** to findByP**k**

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: sequelize don't have findByPK method. (try to change K -> k). More info here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findByPk

Comment: Best wishes, Thank you for your help